# Android studio Message Tool Window enable text mode

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

In this documentation

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/messages-tool-window.html

I can see that we can enable text mode in  Message Tool Window:
[image]

But this button is gone in Message Tool Window in Android Studio

[image]

and I can only useit in tree mode. It is very inconvenient. Where can I switch to text mode ?